# How to properly import a web component to react app?

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I have a catalago-component.js which is a web component. I'm trying to use this web component like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import './../../../assets/catalago-component'
class Loja extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {}
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="page-header">
                    <h1 className="page-title">Loja</h1>
                </div>
                <catalago-component></catalago-component>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
export default Loja
```

but every time I run my react app I get this error

```
src\assets\catalago-component.js
          Line 1:1:       Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
          Line 1:85:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
          Line 1:399:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
          Line 1:599:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
          ...
```

but if I do any changes to the app that makes it recompile then it works just fine

how to solve this error forever? I don't want this app breaking every time I run it for the first time

EDIT: I tried to use this web component with pure html and it worked. take a look

https://eduardopreuss.github.io/web-component/

https://github.com/eduardopreuss/web-component

EDIT 2: link to codesandbox using react + web component https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cohen-ut6mv?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong how I imported, it was a eslint error just like @tsecheukfung01 said in the comments. So I added my web component to `.eslintignore` file and It worked just fine.

more ways to ignore eslint errors [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try something like this:

```
import Catalago from './../../../assets/catalago-component'
```

Then use the component like:

```
<Catalago></Catalago>
```

Assuming your Web component issomething like this:

```
class Catalago extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <speical-web-stuff><speical-web-stuff>
  }
}
```

See:https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html

Comment: It didn't work. I edited my question to make available my web component so others can try to use it too

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you should give your component a name in order to import.

```
import Catalago from './../../../assets/catalago-component'
```

However, sth you may pay attention to.

1. Below syntax expect your component is written in `index.js` under the folder `catalago-component`

````
import Catalago from './assets/catalago-component'   //component locate in file name ```index```

import Catalago from './assets/catalago-component/customizedName.js'
````

2. which type of export used in that component

````
import Catalago from './assets/catalago-component/customizedName.js'  // exporting via ```export default``` keyword

import { Catalago } from './assets/catalago-component/customizedName.js'  //exporting via ```export``` keyword
````

Comment: It didn't work. I edited my question to make available my web component so others can try to use it too

Comment: @eduardoPreuss see whether you can put your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can try out

Comment: @eduardopreuss your ```catalago-component``` is not a React component. The error you get seems sth generated from some syntax checking plugin like ```eslint``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `webpack.config.js` add this line
[image]

Than you can use your component from anywhere inside project.

`import Catalago from 'Components'`

Comment: I don't have webpack installed in my project, isn't there another solution? I mean, it's not even webpack goal to solve this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

The way you import your component is perfectly fine.
A web-component is nothing more than any other HTMLElement like a `<div>` or an `<a>`, meaning this is NOT a React component and cannot be imported and used as such.

Example web-component

```
export class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `My Webcomponent!`
  }
  
  static get tag() {
    return 'my-component';
  }
}

customElements.define(MyComponent.tag, MyComponent);
```

Using the above web-component would look something like:

```
import './../../../assets/MyComponent.js'
...
render() {
   return() {
       <div>
           <my-component></my-component>
       </div>
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import Catalago from './../../../assets/catalago-component'
...
render() {
   return() {
       <div>
           <Catalago //other props/>
       </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I edited my question to make available my web component so others can try to use it too

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).